# AJAX AntiForgery Token not calling controller method

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, antiforgerytoken

I am struggling to call my controller method with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute.

My cshtml/js code :

```
    var wizardRegisterJsonRequest = {
        Email: email,
        Password: password,
        ConfirmPassword: confirmPassword,
        Name: name
    };


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "html",
        url: 'http://localhost:50209/GetAllFonts/WizardRegister',
        data: AddAntiForgeryToken(wizardRegisterJsonRequest),
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#create_account_form').data('busy', true);
            $('#create_account_busy').show();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Success === true) {
                // all good here
            }

            $('#create_account_validation_summary').text(data.Message);
            $('#create_account_validation_summary').show();
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#create_account_form').data('busy', false);
            $('#create_account_busy').hide();
        }
    });

    AddAntiForgeryToken = function (data) {
            alert("adding anti forgery");
          data.__RequestVerificationToken = $('#anti_forgery_token').val();
          return data;
    };
```

Controller code :

```
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult WizardRegister(User usrDetails)
    //public JsonResult WizardLogOn(User usr)
    {
        // string test = ""; // this method WizardRegister is not getting called
    }
```

User model :

```
public class User
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string __RequestVerificationToken { get; set; }
}
```

I am not sure if I need __RequestVerificationToken  in the User model. I am using AntiForgery for the first time.

Please let me know where I am going wrong ...

Thanks,
Rohan.

Update :

View / form code :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "create_account_form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <fieldset>
        <div class="input-fixed">
            <span class="mandatory_wizard">* </span>
            <input type="text" id="registrName" name="registrName" value="rohan" class="name" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="input-fixed">
            <span class="mandatory_wizard">* </span>
            <input type="text" id="registrEmail" name="registrEmail" class="email" value="rohanskosht@gmail.com" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="input-fixed">
            <span class="mandatory_wizard">&nbsp; </span>
            <input type="text" class="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
        </div>
        <div class="input-fixed">
            <span class="mandatory_wizard">* </span>
            <input type="password" id="registerPassword" name="registerPassword" value="12345678" class="password" placeholder="Password: Must be longer than 8 characters.">
        </div>
        <div class="input-fixed">
            <span class="mandatory_wizard">* </span>
            <input type="password" id="registerConfirmPassword" name="registerConfirmPassword" value="12345678" class="confirm-password" placeholder="Confirm Password">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn-modal-login" value="Create your account &gt;&gt;">
        <img id="create_account_busy" style="display: none;" src="./Launch Campaign _ Teeyoot_files/busy.gif" alt="Loading...">
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: No you do not need to include `string __RequestVerificationToken` in your model. It fails because you never add the token to the data your posting. Inspect the html that @Html.AntiForgeryToken()` generates - it does not have a `id="anti_forgery_token"`

Comment: Hi Stephen, thank you for your help, I'm having the value in anti_forgery_token variable ... it has some long string which is the token value ... but still not going in the controller method....

Comment: Show the html its generating! It does not have `id="anti_forgery_token"` (but it does have `name="name=__RequestVerificationToken"`) so you cannot access it by using `__RequestVerificationToken = $('#anti_forgery_token').val();`

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="campaign_currency_id" value="1">
                            <input type="hidden" id="anti_forgery_token" value="oE7rl-HluQGegN7mb_i_hars3G2U2qmndKu_eucgf8EgwnmdkdVXOcomkdgHUH3KQ7_8BPgGtnq-xeYl5wAUTZoioTs5CsSBRj2IVu1dbJU1">

Comment: That is not generated by `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`. How are you generating that html - show your view code.

Comment: I see your point.. I'm definitely going wrong somewhere ..

Comment: <div id="create_account" class="auth-window">
                                            <h2 class="modal-title">Create an account with Teevilla</h2>
                                            <h3 id="create_account_validation_summary" style="display: none; color: red;"></h3>
                                            
<form action="/" id="create_account_form" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="jpWBQxih_WrWwnOkG_OazrR_G37NZpjc5HwZWgplGY_FqNIgK35hhtX3sP2aIXYSaHA11CfIfhFW7vZuhDVLwkXwiKFmwp8SqHOtYlplnIY1" />

Comment: I have __RequestVerificationToken in the form which is generated by html.. Can you suggest me what should be the code changes to be made or any solution ?

Comment: You need to edit you question with the view code (not in comments  is impossible to read when you do not even format it) And show the view code (not the html it generates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` generates a hidden input with `name="__RequestVerificationToken"`. (it does not have an `id` attribute so `$('#anti_forgery_token').val();` will return undefined.

You can access the value using

```
var token= $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
```

However, I strongly suggest you generate the inputs for your properties using the HtmlHelper methods (`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)`, `@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)` etc) rather than generating manual html and then you can simply use

```
data: $('form').serialize()
```

in the ajax call (and you can then delete most of your script). You should also not be hard coding the url (it will fail as soon as you put it into production). Your script simply needs to be

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "html",
    url: '@Url.Action("WizardRegister", "GetAllFonts")', 
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    beforeSend: function () {
        ....
```

You should also be including `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` for each property to get client side validation so invalid forms are not submitted.

Side note: Its not clear from your code why you would use ajax. If the user is registering, then you would want to redirect if successful (and display validation errors if not), so ajax is pointless

Comment: OK, but your then have a lot of extra code to write to property handle validation errors etc (I have never understood why people want do do this rather than the standard/best practice)

Comment: by making some tweaks with your comments / feedback , I am able to now get this working ... var token= $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val(); this just worked fine ... and the method in controller is getting called now ..