# Ajax not sending to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use ajax to update my page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">

            <div align ="center" class="col-md-12">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.YourItem.Comment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder ="add item", id="mango" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.YourItem.Comment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div align ="center" class="col-md-12">
                <button type="button" id="min_knapp" class="btn btn-default-shoppinglist">add </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@if (Model != null)
{
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shoppinglists/_Create.cshtml", Model.MyList)
}
<script>
     $("#min_knapp").click(function() {
        var v1 = jQuery("#mango").val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Create","Shoppinglists")',
            method: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: { mango: v1 }
        }).done(function (d) {
            jQuery("#handleliste").text(d);
        });
    })
</script>
```

my Shoppinglistscontroller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(PartialViewModel d)
        {
            // Add "current group" to each new item and put it in the database
            d.YourItem.GroupID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["selectBoxValue"].Value);
            db.Shoppinglists.Add(d.YourItem);
            db.SaveChanges();

            pv.MyList = db.Shoppinglists.ToList();

            return PartialView("_Liste");
        }
```

when i press my button i am expecting the data from my textfield to be sent to the controller and then post the result to the page, but nothing happens. What is wrong?

Comment: *"but nothing happens"* is not a proper problem statement, especially when ajax is involved.Something probably does happen.  All the clues are in browser dev tools where you can inspect actual request made. Also use error handlers

Comment: All you passing back is a name/value pair for `mango: someValue` and you model does not even contain a property named `Mango`. And you have a `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` on the POST method but are not passing the token which will throw an exception. Remove the attribute and change the method to `public ActionResult Create(string mango)`

Comment: well i did the debug and got this error message:

POST http://localhost:50229/Shoppinglists/Create 500 (Internal Server Error).

the problem seems to be  with  send@jquery-1.10.2.js:8720

jquery-1.12.2 line 8720 contains:xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );

Comment: You did not debug your code. Open the browser tools (Network tab) and inspect the response and you would have seen the error relating to the `AntiForgeryToken`

Comment: when debugging i recieve this error:
The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.
what is wrong?

Comment: Read my first comment! Your not passing the token to the method, so either pass it (refer [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35075961/ajax-antiforgery-token-not-calling-controller-method/35076552#35076552) for an example) or delete `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` from your method